# Transforming pyspark to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that I want to transform to pandas.

```
data= [
    ("A", 1, datetime(2023, 5, 19, 12, 1, 0)),
    ("B", 1, datetime(2023, 5, 19, 12, 1, 0)),
    ("C", 1, datetime(2023, 5, 19, 12, 1, 0)),
    ("D", 1, datetime(2023, 5, 19, 12, 5, 0)),
]

schema = StructType(
    [   
        StructField('id_col', StringType(), True),
        StructField('id2_col', IntegerType(), True),
        StructField('timestamp', TimestampType(), True),
    ]
)

dfs = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

dfp = dfs.toPandas()
```

When I do this however I get an error:

```
TypeError: Casting to unit-less dtype 'datetime64' is not supported. Pass e.g. 'datetime64[ns]' instead.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works well for `PySpark 3.4.0` and `Pandas 1.5.3` but not with `Pandas 2.0.2`. You can downgrade your version of Pandas until PySpark fixes the code or you can convert your `timestamp` column as string before to exporting it to Pandas.

```
dfp = (dfs.withColumn('timestamp', dfs.timestamp.cast('string'))
          .toPandas().astype({'timestamp': 'datetime64[ns]'}))
```

Output:

```
>>> dfp
  id_col  id2_col           timestamp
0      A        1 2023-05-19 12:01:00
1      B        1 2023-05-19 12:01:00
2      C        1 2023-05-19 12:01:00
3      D        1 2023-05-19 12:05:00

>>> dfp.dtypes
id_col               object
id2_col               int32
timestamp    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Reproducible bug with Pandas:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2023-05-19 12:01:00']})
>>> df.astype({'timestamp': 'datetime64'})
...
TypeError: Casting to unit-less dtype 'datetime64' is not supported. Pass e.g. 'datetime64[ns]' instead.

>>> df.astype({'timestamp': 'datetime64[ns]'})
            timestamp
0 2023-05-19 12:01:00
```

Comment: @andKaae. Does it solve your problem?